# Mapping float value to function depending on specified intervals

Tags: c++, c++11

## The goal

Given a main interval, `[0,1]` for example, break that interval in any number of subintervals, for example `[0,0.2) , [0.2,0.5) , [0.5,1]`.
Now map different functions to each subinterval generated:

```
[0,0.2)   ~> a( float x )
[0.2,0.5) ~> b( float x )
[0.5,1]   ~> c( float x )
```

Call that mapping function `map`.
The `map` mapping function is dessigned 
to get a floating-point value on the main interval, and call the corresponding function mapped. That is, given an input value `x = 0.3`, `map` calls `b(0.3)`:

```
map(0.3); //Should call b(0.3)
```

My question is: **What is the proper/best way to implement this on C++?**

## Attemped solutions:

I have tried a solution which consists on represent intervals as a pair of float values, i.e. `using interval = std::pair<float,float>;`, and using that interval type as key of a (unordered)map:

```
void map_function( float x )
{
    std::map<interval,std::function<void(float)>> map;

    map[{0.0,0.2}] = [](float){ ... }; //a
    map[{0.2,0.5}] = [](float){ ... }; //b
    map[{0.5,1.0}] = [](float){ ... }; //c

    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( map ) , 
                            std::end( map ) ,
                            [x]( const interval& interval )
    {
        return x >= interval.first && x < interval.second;
    });

    if( it != std::end( map ) )
        *it( x );
    else
        throw "x out of bounds or subintervals ill-formed";
}
```

This solution seems to work, but has some minnor problems I think:

- **It has O(n) complexity**, given n subintervals. Is there any way to perform this kind of function in O(1)?
- **Is `std::map` the proper container for this work?**: The purpose of associative containers is to map from a key to a value, but here the key of the map is not the input itself, is a processed form of the input (The interval which the input value belongs to).
  *I have tried C++11's `std::unordered_map` too, but seems like there is no standard hash function for float pairs. That surprises me, but falls into another question. Keep on topic :P*

## Alternative solutions? Requeriments

I know about interval libraries, like Boost Interval and Boost Interval Container libraries, but I need a solution which **relies on Standard Library facilities only**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intervals are adjacent to each other then use just starting points as keys and instead of using `find()` use `lower_bound()`. You cannot make it faster than `log2(N)` in general case. If you know what the maximum decimal precision is I suggest you use int64_t as a key. The transformation is `int64_t ikey = 10eX * dkey`, where `X` is the maximum precision.

Comment: And if they are not adjacent you should be able to get the same result by building your own balanced binary tree and having the nodes have a concept of falling in their interval as their equals case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to **O(lg n)** complexity. Specifically, the [lower bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) form [#algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) libary. If you have a vector of `tuple <double, ptr_function>` you can use bitary search for it. If ranges are a specific const length or length is multiple of some number, you can do it in **O(1)** time. For example:

```
multiple of 0.1
Ranges: [0;0.4) = a, [0.4;0.5) = b, [0.5;1) = c
table = {a,a,a,b,c,c,c,c,c}
Getting for x : table[floor(x*10)]
```

Edit: If you want to keep map, you can use map's [lower bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound).

Comment: Std::map is implemented as a binary tree (I.E. it's an ordered map), and has a lower_bound search. No need to reinvent the wheel. I agree with the O(1) case though.

Comment: @aruisdante ok, I wanted to emphasize that the map is not necessary. Maybe I should mention this. However, I added information about it. Thank you.

Comment: Correct, but then you have to self-manage the tree on new element insertion. std::map takes care of that boilerplate for you, and makes the intent of your use immediately clear to anyone working with your code later on.

Comment: You have a point. The map could be a better option. Especially when ranges will change dynamically, but not when the most important is memory. Search complexity is the same, construction could be linear on vector, on map it's **O(n lg n)**. The question of priorities.